# Jordan form of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, jordan-normal-form, linear-groups

Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix.

Then there exists $Q$ also orthogonal such that $QAQ^* = D$ for some diagonal matrix $D$.

Following this post:[Elements of SO(n) is block-diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362624/elements-of-son-is-block-diagonalizable)

I'm not sure how we got that the Jordan from contains the block matrix $R_t $from $|\lambda|=1$
$$R_{t}=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\cos(t) & \sin(t)\\
-\sin(t) & \cos(t) 
\end{array}\right).$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We start with a real square matrix $A$. If $A$ has an eigenvalue  $a+bi$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$ then $a-bi$ is also an eigenvalue. Note tha your $b$ can be my $-b$. Suppose $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector for  the eigenvalue $a+bi$. Write $\mathbf v=\mathbf v^{\prime}+ \mathbf v^{\prime \prime}i$ where $\mathbf{v^{\prime},v^{\prime \prime}}$ are real. Let $P=[\mathbf{v^{\prime \prime}\vdots v^{\prime}}]$. Then $$AP=P\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a \end{bmatrix}$$ Note that if your $b$ is my $-b$,then  $b$ and $-b$ will be interchanged.Thus $$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a \end{bmatrix}.$$ In polar form, $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}.$$ If $A$ is orthogonal, then every eigenvalue is on the unit circle, so $r=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
$$
Because an orthogonal matrix $\ A\ $ is normal, has real entries, and eigenvalues of absolute value $\ 1\ $, it has a diagonalisation of the form
\begin{align}
U^\dagger&AU=\\
&\text{diag}\big(e^{it_1},e^{-it_1},e^{it_2},e^{-it_2},\dots,e^{it_r},e^{-it_r},1,1,\dots,1,-1,-1,\dots,-1\big)\ .
\end{align}
If
$$
W\eqdef\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&-i\\-i&1}
$$
it is easy to check that
\begin{align}
W^\dagger\pmatrix{e^{it}&0\\0&e^{-it}}W&=W^\dagger\pmatrix{\cos t+i\sin t&0\\0&\cos t-i\sin t}W\\
&=\pmatrix{\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t&\cos t}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if
\begin{align}
V&\eqdef\\
&\pmatrix{W&0_{2\times2}&\dots&0_{2\times2}&0_{2\times(n-2r)}\\
0_{2\times2}&W 
&\dots&0_{2\times2}&0_{2\times(n-2r)}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0_{2\times2}& 0_{2\times2}&
\dots& W &0_{2\times(n-2r)}\\
0_{(n-2r)
\times2}&0_{(n-2r)
\times2}&\dots&0_{(n-2r)
\times2}&I_{(n-2r)
\times(n-2r)}}\ ,
\end{align}
then conjugation of $\ U^\dagger AU\ $ by $\ V\ $:
$$
V^\dagger U^\dagger AUV=(UV)^\dagger AUV
$$
will turn each $\ 2\times2\ $ block $\ \pmatrix{e^{it_k}&0\\0&e^{-it_k}}\ $ on the diagonal of $\ U^\dagger AU\ $ into the corresponding $\ 2\times2\ $ block $\ \pmatrix{\cos t_k&\sin t_k\\-\sin t_k&\cos t_k}\ $ on the diagonal of $\ (UV)^\dagger AUV\ $.